# Is there a picture of Lex Luthor's desk from the "Superman" movie?

Tags: dc, props, superman-1978

I have acquired a desk that was supposedly a prop in *Superman the Movie*, shot in Calgary, Alberta. I would like some way to authenticate if it's the original.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I assume you've tried watching the movie?  What details are you looking for that would help you decide it's the original prop and not a replica?

Comment: http://www.moviepropcollectors.com/magazine/2016/12/18/how-to-authenticate-props-movie-memorabilia-and-pop-entertainment-items/all/1/

Comment: This would be a far more interesting question if you posted a picture/s of the desk you've bought and explained why you think it is/isn't genuine

Comment: keep us updated - would be interested to know what the results are (for privacy sake, you could delete this question and ask a new one simply saying "is *this* desk the same one" and not get into who is in possesion of said item). Good luck - hope it turns out positive - that would be cool

Comment: comments of a 'caveat emptor' nature aren't necessary. OP isn't necessarily expressing buyer's remorse or even saying they purchased it *because* of the connection to the film - or even that they bought it at all. Could have been in grandma's attic for all we know @tilley31

Comment: I agree that posting your own picture of the desk would be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

[This page](https://www.capedwonder.com/superman-the-movie-gallery-superman-confronts-lex-luthor/) has some images (click to enlarge).

[image: Superman confronts Luthor at his desk] [image: Luthor at his desk with henchmen]

[image: Luthor's desk in the background] [image: Superman fighting in front of the desk]

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

Here are some screenshots from [movie-screencaps.com](https://movie-screencaps.com/superman-1978/). You can see a front shot and a back shot, although the desk is covered in Lex's evil doings, including used orange paper cups.

[image: front shot of the desk and Lex Luthor, who is reading a document, facing the walls of books]

[image: back shot of the desk, several documents have been put on it, including a newspaper; several lit lamps]

[image: roughly the same picture as above, but now with Superman in the middle of the room]

Really the only details I can see are the edge trims.